# How can I read with SQL COUNT(*) the Number of entries

Tags: c#, sql, count, repeater

How can I read with SQL COUNT(*) the Number of entries

Hi,
I don't know to read the number of entries in a table. (I would like to use asp:Repeader)

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table";
```

---

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater01" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "????????") %>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What is the ???? Statement?
Thanks.

Edit: This is my SQL-Statement:

```
select t.tip_adi, count(oda.oda_tip_id) from oteldb.tip t 
left join (select oda_tip_id from oteldb.oda o 
       where not exists (
              select null from oteldb.rezervasyon r 
              where r.rezervasyon_oda_id = o.oda_id 
              and r.rezervasyon_gt <= '2012-01-22' 
              and '2012-01-03' <= r.rezervasyon_c
       ) ) oda on oda.oda_tip_id = t.tip_id 
group by t.tip_adi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alias the COUNT(*), like this:

`sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS MyCount FROM Table";`

Now you have a defined column name you can begin to use as `MyCount`.

So now you can do:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyCount") %>
```

Based on your comment your query would become this:

`select t.tip_adi, count(oda.oda_tip_id) AS MyCount from oteldb.tip t left join (select oda_tip_id from oteldb.oda o where not exists (select null from oteldb.rezervasyon r where r.rezervasyon_oda_id = o.oda_id and r.rezervasyon_gt <= '2012-01-22' and '2012-01-03' <= r.rezervasyon_ct) ) oda on oda.oda_tip_id = t.tip_id group by t.tip_adi`

Notice the "MyCount".  Now you can use what I posted above to bind that value.

Comment: thanks JonH. Its my query `select t.tip_adi, count(oda.oda_tip_id) from oteldb.tip t left join (select oda_tip_id from oteldb.oda o where not exists (select null from oteldb.rezervasyon r where r.rezervasyon_oda_id = o.oda_id and r.rezervasyon_gt <= '2012-01-22' and '2012-01-03' <= r.rezervasyon_ct) ) oda on oda.oda_tip_id = t.tip_id group by t.tip_adi ` how can i this?

Comment: @Mehmet - You need to mention that in your question, I am answering what you asked!  But with your query just do as I stated alias the count and use it.  Like this `select t.tip_adi, count(oda.oda_tip_id) AS MyCount from oteldb.tip t left join (select oda_tip_id from oteldb.oda o where not exists (select null from oteldb.rezervasyon r where r.rezervasyon_oda_id = o.oda_id and r.rezervasyon_gt <= '2012-01-22' and '2012-01-03' <= r.rezervasyon_ct) ) oda on oda.oda_tip_id = t.tip_id group by t.tip_adi`

Answer (score 1):

you can use As alias for your sql query. try like this,

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS someCount FROM Table";



<asp:Repeater id="Repeater01" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "someCount") %>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your sql and asp.net repeater are fitting together, but if you actually want to execute a `SELECT COUNT(*)` then you would normally use the ADO.NET `ExecuteScalar()` to read back the result of the count(*) as an int, then just display it.

Or are you saying you have a lot of actual results that you are displaying with a repeater, and you just want to total up a number?

The question isn't very clear...